# Integration of the function derivative wrt the function

Tags: integration, wolfram-alpha

According to [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bf%27%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Cf%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D)

$$ \int f'(x)df(x) = f'(x) f(x) + constant $$

I am trying to get the RHS, but alas... I tried to apply integration by parts and to apply it twice

Comment: That looks wrong. Unless I am mistaken is $\int_a^b f'(x) df(x) = \int_a^b f'(x)^2 dx$ for a differentiable function $f$.

Comment: @MartinR You are not mistaken. Still https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BD%5Bf%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D%2Cf%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D

Comment: I have no idea how WA interprets the input, but that makes no sense. Btw, I have never seen an “indefinite” Riemann-Stieltjes integral (i.e. without lower and upper bound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too long for comment*: As you and MartinR suspect, WA is mistaken due to a bug* in the Wolfram Language function `Integrate` that has been addressed (but not fixed!) as recently as version 13.2.0 of *Mathematica*.

I happen to have just the right versions of *Mathematica* installed that demonstrate this. Here's the output from 12.2.0 :

```
In[]:= $Version
Out[]= "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

In[]:= Integrate[f'[x], f[x]]
Out[]= f[x] Derivative[1][f][x]
```

And from 13.2.0 :

```
In[]:= $Version
Out[]= "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)"

In[]:= Integrate[f'[x] f[x], f[x]]
Out[]= 1/2 f[x]^2 Derivative[1][f][x]
```

(NB: `Derivative[1][f][x]` means "`Derivative` of order `1` of `f` with respect to `x`", i.e. $f'(x)$)

But this result is still not quite right (outside of *Mathematica*, anyway; it's possible this behavior is by design). The problem is that `Integrate[expr, var]` is strictly integrating w.r.t. `var` and treats everything else constant. In this case the symbol `f[x]` is the variable, and the dependency on `x` is ignored. Similarly, computing a derivative w.r.t. $f(x)$ also gives a bad result in both aforementioned versions,

```
In[]:= D[f[x] f'[x], f[x]]
Out[]= Derivative[1][f][x]
```

whereas one might expect, using the chain rule,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{df(x)}[f(x)f'(x)] &= f'(x) + f(x) \frac{df'(x)}{df(x)} \\
&= f'(x) + f(x) \frac{df'(x)}{dx} \frac{dx}{df(x)} \\
&= f'(x) + \frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)}
\end{align*}$$

Doing the same for your original output, the same process yields

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{df(x)} \left[\frac12 f(x)^2 f'(x)\right] &= \frac12 \frac{df(x)^2}{df(x)} f'(x) + \frac12 f(x)^2 \frac{df'(x)}{df(x)} \\
&= f(x) f'(x) + \frac12 f(x)^2 \frac{df'(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{df(x)} \\
&= f(x) f'(x) + \frac12 f(x)^2 \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}
\end{align*}$$

which would mean WA's antiderivative only applies to a certain family of functions $f$, namely those for which $f'\neq0$ and $f''=0$.